# POST method of Powerbi api failing but GET is working (Python)

Tags: python, powershell, api, powerbi

I'm trying to refresh a dataflow using python. It is working for me in Powershell. I'm not sure if I'm using Python correctly. Using Python, I'm able to do get method working correctly.

Python (get method :-> working)

```
import requests
groupID = <groupid>
#url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/capacities'
header = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}','Content-Type':'application/json'}
datasets_request_url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/' + groupID + '/datasets'
response = requests.get(url=datasets_request_url, headers=header)
```

Python failing (POST Method)

```
dataflowid = <dataflowid>
dataflowrefresh_url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/' + groupID + '/dataflows/'+dataflowid+'/refreshes'
response = requests.post(url=dataflowrefresh_url, headers=header)
```

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:

PowerShell (POST method working)

```
$workspaceid = <groupid>
$dataflowid = <dataflowid>
$uri = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$workspaceid/Dataflows/$dataflowid/refreshes"

# Build JSON, convert back and forth as we're just defining it as a string.
$json = '{"notifyOption": "MailOnFailure"}' | ConvertFrom-Json
$body = $json | ConvertTo-Json

# Refresh the dataflow
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authHeader -body $body -Method POST -Verbose
```

If I remove the parameter $body, it fails with error 400. I don't know how to convert the working Powershell api call to Python.

Used the same token generated by below code. POST method worked in Powershell but not in Python, GET worked in both.

```
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority=authority_url,

                                         validate_authority=True,
                                         api_version=None)
    
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_url, client_id, client_secret)
access_token = token.get('accessToken')
```

Comment: where is the data your sending?!

Comment: I'm trying to refresh the dataflow in a workspace. Convert powershell to Python script. Is data some mandatory parameter for requests.post method?

Comment: What type of authentication are you using to generate the access token? What permissions does that identity have exactly?

Comment: Tried using the same token generated by Python script in both powershell and python. POST worked in Powershell not in Python.

Comment: Maby also write Dataflows instead of dataflows in the  url in python? (I know usually it doesn't matter, but who knows...)

Comment: Try `requests.post(url=dataflowrefresh_url, headers=header, json={"notifyOption": "MailOnFailure"})`

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked. I had to give refreshRequest : 'y' in the parameter. Thanks to Postman app. Updating the answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/' + workspaceID + '/dataflows/' +dataflowid+ '/refreshes'
payload= {'refreshRequest': 'y'}
data = json.dumps(payload)
headers = header
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Using refreshRequest : 'Y' made it work. In powershell, I didn't have to give this parameter.